# Firefox 12.0 and Selenium 2 : Native Events are not supported

Tags: firefox, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver

When running Selenium 2.21.0 build using the webdriver, I get the following error when running against Firefox 12.0 :

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: Cannot perform native interaction: Could not load native events component.
Command duration or timeout: 20.08 seconds
Build info: version: '2.2.1', revision: '16551', time: '2012-04-11 21:42:35'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_26'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:175)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:459)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ExecuteMethod.execute(ExecuteMethod.java:47)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteMouse.mouseMove(RemoteMouse.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.internal.MouseAction.moveToLocation(MouseAction.java:31)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.ClickAndHoldAction.perform(ClickAndHoldAction.java:39)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.CompositeAction.perform(CompositeAction.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:121)
    at isishelper.ActionHelper.placement_placeSampleOnContainer(ActionHelper.groovy:195)
...
```

My code in this case is as follows :

```
List sourceSamples = sourceTable.findElements((By.className("x-grid-row")))
List poolTargets = driver.findElements(By.className("pool-box"))
target = poolTargets[0]    
def source = sourceSamples[0]
// Then drag and drop the sample to target
(new Actions(driver)).dragAndDrop(source, target).perform()
```

I'm assuming this is missing functionality as Selenium 2.21 was released before Firefox 12.0, rather than an error setting up the driver on my part?

Checking the driver properties :

```
driver.getCapabilities().asMap().each { 
             index, value -> println("$index : $value") 
}
```

> ```
> browserName : firefox
> nativeEvents : false
> takesScreenshot : true
> version : 12.0
> ```

But while creating the driver with a profile I get nativeEvents = true :

```
profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true); 
println profile.getProperties()
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile)
```

> ```
> [enableNativeEvents:true, 
> class:class org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile,
> additionalPreferences:org.openqa.selenium.firefox.Preferences@82d37]
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium 2.29.0 is released with the support for FF18 (for native events).
Here is the link to update : http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/rb/CHANGES.

May be updating to FF18 and selenium-webdriver (2.29.0) may help you.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely native events are not yet supported in webdriver 2.21. According to [changelog](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/java/CHANGELOG) only FF10 and 11 currently implement this feature.

I don't know if this is related to the problem, but in the last line of your code shouldn't you call build() before calling perform()? (this would have to be done in Java)

More stacktrace could be helpful. On which line are you getting this error? Have you tried setting native events explicitly to false?

Comment: - Thanks, if Native Events aren't ready for FF12 then that would probably explain most of this.

Comment: Extended the stack trace, and checked that I don't need to add .build() in my groovy code... this works fine against a Chrome Browser.  

I'll look into setting the NativeEvents specifically.

Comment: You could try some ugly workarounds. Instead of using just dragAndDrop you could try splitting it to the more specific actions

new Actions(driver).clickAndHold(element).moveByOffset(1, 1).release();

The offset can be calculated by using getLocation() and getSize() method on every element you want to interact with and doing simple math.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium 2.22.0 has been released, and the changelog says they now support native events in Firefox 12.  I've tested it, and it seems to be working great.